# Help on Mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to do trigger after Inserting on a table called jos_jquarks_quizzes, I need to create a course name which will have the same name as the quizz name , but its own id,

Tables

```
jos_jquarks_quizzes
    id
    title
    description
    course_id

jos_jquarks_users_training
    id
    quiz_id
    user_id
    agree
```

current approach

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO jos_users_trainings
  (jos_users_trainings.quiz_id) VALUES 


    SELECT jos_jquarks_quizzes.id FROM jos_jquarks_quizzes 
END
```

Can you please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_jos_jquarks_quizzes_each AFTER INSERT ON jos_jquarks_quizzes 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO jos_users_trainings
      (quiz_id) VALUES (new.id); 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

In a trigger the virtual table `new` holds the newly inserted values.

In an `update` or `delete` trigger the virtual table `old` holds the values before the change.